# Heat Map With Red Color Range For Negative Values And Green Color Range For Positive Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, heatmap

I am using heat map of **highchart**. Its working fine.

Now i want to set color ranges for values. Like green color range for positive values and red color range for negative values.

Is there any option i can use to achieve it ?

[Heat Map Sample](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/treemap-coloraxis)

Comment: You can also use [dataClasses](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.dataClassColor)

Answer (score 2):

U need to Change the min color and max Color

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        colorAxis: {
            minColor: '#00FF00',
            maxColor: '#FF0000'
        },
        series: [{
            type: "treemap",
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            data: [{
                name: 'Positive A',
                value: 6,
                colorValue: 1
            }, {
                name: 'Positive B',
                value: 6,
                colorValue: 2
            }, {
                name: 'Positive C',
                value: 4,
                colorValue: 3
            }, {
                name: 'Neutral',
                value: 3,
                colorValue: 4
            }, {
                name: 'Negative E',
                value: 2,
                colorValue: 5
            }, {
                name: 'Negative F',
                value: 2,
                colorValue: 6
            }, {
                name: 'Negative G',
                value: 1,
                colorValue: 7
            }]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/460nrx95) for it

Answer (score 0):

You can mention color to be used while preparing the data to be loaded to chart, you can add your checks and choose at data preparing part.

Example:

```
           data: [{
                name: 'A',
                value: 6,
                color: "red"
            }, {
                name: 'B',
                value: 6,
                color: "red"
            }, {
                name: 'C',
                value: 4,
                color:"green"
            }, {
                name: 'D',
                value: 3,
                color: "red"
            }, {
                name: 'E',
                value: 2,
                color:"green"
            }, {
                name: 'F',
                value: 2,
                color:"green"
            }, {
                name: 'G',
                value: 1,
                color:"yellow"
            }]
```

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/o83k4gkn/)